# How do I select contact after finding it ? Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to select an option from a list. Once I search, should be able to select and show it on the search bar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb7uE.png). Here's what I have done so far.

I am able to search contact. All I want to do next is select that contact from list and add it to search bar (like gmail and all).

**template**

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="findContact($event)" placeholder="Enter display name">
    <button ion-button color="light" (click)="findContact($event)" icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-searchbar>

  <ion-list [hidden]="!search">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of contactsfound">{{item.displayName}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```js
findContact(ev: any) {
  let fields: ContactFieldType[] = ['displayName'];

  const options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = ev.target.value;
  options.multiple = true;
  options.hasPhoneNumber = true;

  this.contact.find(fields, options).then((contacts) => {
    this.contactsfound = contacts;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts[0]));
  });

  if (this.contactsfound.length == 0) {
    this.contactsfound.push({
      displayName: 'No Contacts found'
    });
  }
  this.search = true;
}
```

Comment: Is [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9HvbnKbJh4paHRh1yYEB?p=preview) something like what you are looking for? if it is I'll write out a more detailed answer explaining it (I know it's angular and it looks horrible with no styles but the syntax is the same)

Comment: @0mpurdy This is similar to what I am looking for. Basically when I search and select the contact name from native contact list, it should be show on the same search bar.

Comment: Ok so are you asking about the creating of a filtered list, binding to the template or styling? There is quite a bit of information on these questions already answered here on StackOverflow - if you could split up your problem into smaller chunks it would be helpful :)

Comment: @0mpurdy I couldn't find it on stackoverflow. It would be great if you can share the link.  I am not sure how to explain my problem but let me try. I am creating chat application. So basically I should be able to search and select multiple contacts from the list and add it to the searchbar itself. I have managed to access list of contacts, search and filter. But after filtering, I am not sure how to select them and that is the question: how do I select option once I filter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I found the solution. Basically I was talking about ion-chips. I was going through docs and found it. I have used ion-chips under ng-container; added some function that will select option from the ion-list (note: not from the ion-select) and show that selected option as a chip in the html template :)