# An error is "Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined" in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am creating a caller name speaker app in ionic 4. For this, I am able to get incoming caller state and number. With the number, I want to find a name in the contact name and there I am facing the issue.

first, I did a run command: ionic Cordova run android to run the app in the device then inspect the app using chrome inspect and in chrome inspect I am getting this error.

```
polyfills.js:3040 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
at home-home-module.js:275
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:2749)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (polyfills.js:2508)
at polyfills.js:3247
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2781)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2553)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2959) TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
at http://localhost/home-home-module.js:275:87
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2749:26)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2508:43)
at http://localhost/polyfills.js:3247:34
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2781:31)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2553:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost/polyfills.js:2959:35)
```

here code page.ts file:

```
declare var window: any;

//phone calls
phonecalls() {
window.PhoneCallTrap.onCall((obj) => {
  alert("CHANGE STATE: " + obj.state);
  var callObj = JSON.parse(obj),
    state = callObj.state,
    callingNumber = callObj.incomingNumber;

  console.log("obj: " + obj);

  //working
  alert("callingNumber STATE: " + callingNumber);

  //call name get
  let fields: ContactFieldType[] = ['displayName'];

  const options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = callingNumber;
  options.multiple = true;
  options.hasPhoneNumber = true;

  this.contact.find(fields, options).then((contacts) => {
    this.contactsfoundcallingNumber = contacts;
    console.log("contactsfound call", this.contactsfoundcallingNumber[0].displayName);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts[0].displayName));
  });

  console.log("Hell lvl2: " + this.contactsfoundcallingNumber);

  switch (state) {
    case "RINGING":
      console.log("Phone is ringing", callingNumber);
      break;
    case "OFFHOOK":
      console.log("Phone is off-hook");
      break;

    case "IDLE":
      console.log("Phone is idle");
      break;
  }
});
}
```

Help, please...

Comment: Where does the `this.contact.find` comes? What do you have in `this.contact`? It seems like the problem comes inside that function. You need to provide extra code and it would be very helpfull that you add an stackblitz example.

Comment: I have only this code nothing else and you can check here this guy did something interesting and with his code, we can search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338215/how-do-i-select-contact-after-finding-it-ionic-2

Comment: The guy in that example probably have `this.contact` declared. Do an live example in stackblitz so we can help you, because we need to know the objects values. Probably he has in the constructor `private contacts: Contacts` that comes with an import from `@ionic-native/contacts/ngx`.

Comment: yes, I am using ionic contact plugin and imported in app.module.ts and hope.page.ts file.

Comment: well, I found an issue. incoming call in I am getting number with country code and save contact number is without country code so that's why I am getting undefined

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code I would log to console contacts object to see how many elements it has and what is the value of displayName in those elements.

Comment: this is not answer

Comment: No, but it can help to find the answer. Perhaps I should have made it a comment instead...

Comment: So, contacts object is empty? If so, then displayName is undefined as the error suggests. Unfortunately I don't know why it is empty.

Comment: well you can see in code callingNumber (the number found), and then I added callingNumber  in contact filter